# Converting String to DateTime in SSJS

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to set a default value on an inputText field that has a dateTimeHelper associated with it. The following computed default value works:

```
return @Today();
```

[image: img1]

However, I need to set the default date value 7 days from a date that is stored as a string on a document. So I tried the following:

```
var date:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime(doc.getItemValue("EffDate")[0]);
log.logEvent("date= " + date); // returns 09/01/2013

var newDate = new Date(date);
log.logEvent("newDate= " + newDate); // returns NaN

var datePlus7 = @Adjust(newDate,0,0,7,0,0,0,"[InLocalTime]");
log.logEvent("datePlus7= " + datePlus7); // returns NaN

return datePlus7;
```

Which does not work because datePlus7 is NaN. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use method `toJavaDate()` of DateTime class instead of Date constructor "new Date(date)":

```
var newDate = date.toJavaDate()
```